# What is System.Reactive.Linq.Observαble? (note the alpha)

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

Whatever is `System.Reactive.Linq.Observαble`?

Note the Greek letter 'alpha' in place of the 'a'. Observαble not Observable

Found about a hundred classes (all `internal`) in this namespace in the assembly

> // C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Reactive
>   Extensions\v2.0\Binaries.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Reactive.Linq.dll
>   // System.Reactive.Linq, Version=2.0.20823.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Per [this comment from Bart de Smet](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Bart-De-Smet-Inside-Rx-V2-Beta#c634675182066113791) :

> You're seeing an internal namespace with a Greek alpha in its name to
>   make the call stack look exactly like the methods you wrote. We can't
>   have inner classes such as Where nested inside Observable, because
>   there's already a method with that name. So, the closest approximation
>   was an Observαble namespace with classes such as Where in it.
>
> Unfortunately, the namespace shows up in IntelliSense at this point,
>   due to some complexities around the IDE's handling of
>   InternalsVisibleTo. We're aware of this problem and are looking into
>   it.

Answer (score 0):

It's an `internal` namespace of the `System.Reactive.Linq DLL`, so not meant to be exposed to the outside world.